# Is semidirect product unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semidirect-product

This is about semi direct product on Dummit and Foote algebra text book.
Why is this statement true?

> **Theorem 12.** Suppose $G$ is a group with subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that
>
> 1. $H\trianglelefteq G$, and
> 2. $H\cap K=1$
>
> Let $\varphi:K\to\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ be the homomorphism defined by mappinf $k\in K$ to the automorphism of left conjugation by $k$ on $H$. Then $HK\cong H\rtimes K$. In particular, if $G=HK$ with $H$ and $K$ satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$, then $G$ is the semidirect product of $H$ and $K$.

I think semidirect product of $H,K$ depends on the choice of homomorphism $\varphi$.

But once $H,K$ is determined, $HK$ is unique, I think.

For example, if $H =\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $K=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ then $Aut(H)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Then homomorphism from $K$ to $Aut(H)$ is not unique.
(Namely, there are two cases.)

So semidirect product of $H,K$ is not unique.

So how can I understand this situation?

Maybe, $HK$ is not unique, and there is a theorem such that $HK$ is isomorphic to the semidirect product of $H,K$ for some homomorphism $\varphi$?

Thanks!

Comment: once $H,K$ are determined (as subgroups of some group $G$) then $HK$ is unique. but knowing $H,K$ *as groups* only, $HK$ is not always uniquely determined; even it doesn't make sense. If we have given $\varphi\colon K\rightarrow H$ a homomorphism, then there is a way to determine $HK$ uniquely.

Comment: Note that the notation $HK$ doesn't even make sense if $H$ and $K$ aren't already subgroups of some group $G$. To produce (outer) semidirect products out of two abstract groups $H$ and $K$, you need the data of a homomorphism $K \to \operatorname{Aut}H$. Conversely, each semidirect product of $H$ and $K$ yields a homomorphism $K \to \operatorname{Aut}H$, and any two semidirect products that yield the same homomorphism are isomorphic (they are each isomorphic to the outer semidirect product constructed through the homomorphism).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(A)**
You are right: semi-direct product of $H$ by $K$ depends on choice of homomorphism $\varphi\colon K\rightarrow Aut(H)$.

**(B)** When we start with group $G$, and subgroups $H,K$ with

(1) $H\trianglelefteq G$,

(2) $HK=G$,

(3) $H\cap K=1$,

then (the known group) $G$ *is called* as internal semi-direct product of $H$ by $K$. Here, we already know that $H$ is normal in $G$, hence every element $k\in K$ determines an automorphism of $H$: $h\mapsto khk^{-1}$. This gives a homomorphism $\varphi\colon K\rightarrow Aut(H)$.

**(C)** Suppose *we don't know* $G$, but we start with *groups* $H$ and $K$ (not subgroups), with a homomorphism $\varphi\colon K\rightarrow Aut(H)$ [like, in your question, see after **..for example...**].
Then we can *construct a group* $G$ such that (roughly) $H$ and $K$ satisfy (1), (2) and (3) above. In this case, the *constructed group* $G$ is called as *external semi-direct product* of $H$ by $K$.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still confused. I've been reading about classification of finite group of small order. Here is what is confusing. If We know H,N and suppose HN = G.(Think H,N as a sylow subgroup of G). then yes, G can be Semidirect product of H,N for some corresponding homomorphism from H to Aut(K). i.e. For given (phi), G is determined. But Is there any other possibility that G is not isomorphic to the semidirect product of H and N, but G is isomorphic to HN?

Comment: To make clear your last question: let me know, what is given complete data (hypothesis) in your question, and what is expectation?

Comment: Ah...! (B) solve my problem. For Given H,K, that gives (Phi) and for that (phi) HK isomorphic to the semiproduct of H and K. Thus, HK should be isomorphic to the semiproduct of H and K for some (Phi). So we only consider the case all possible (Phi), and correspoding Semidirect product of H and K. and There are no other options! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I find it helpful to distinguish between the *inner* semidirect product and the *outer* semidirect product. (Similiar to the distinction between the inner direct sum and the outer direct sum of vector (sub)spaces.)

Given a group $G$ and two subgroups $H$ and $N$ of $G$, the group $G$ is called the *inner semidirect product of $H$ and $N$ with $N$ normal*, if we have $NH = G$ and $H \cap N = 1$, and $N$ is normal in $G$. We then write
$$
  G = N \rtimes H \,.
$$
(This notion of an inner semidirect product does not depend on any homomorphism.)

Given on the other hand any two groups $N$ and $H$ and a group homomorphism $\theta \colon H \to \operatorname{Aut}(N)$, the corresponding *outer semidirect product* $N \rtimes_\theta H$ is defined as the set $N \times H$ together with the multiplication
$$
 (n_1, h_1) \cdot (n_2, h_2) := (n_1 \theta(h_1)(n_2), h_1 h_2) \,.
$$
Note that this group $N \rtimes_\theta H$ very much depends on $\theta$.

Now what is the connection between these two?

If $G$ is a group and $H$ and $N$ are two subgroups of $G$ such that $G = N \rtimes H$, then $N$ is normal in $G$. The conjugation action of $H$ on $G$ does therefore restrict to an action of $H$ on $N$. From this we get a group homomorphism
$$
  \theta \colon H \to \mathrm{Aut}(N)
  \quad\text{given by}\quad
  \theta(h)(n) = hnh^{-1} \,.
$$
It can then be checked that the map
$$
 N \rtimes_\theta H \to G = N \rtimes H, \quad (n,h) \mapsto n \cdot h
$$
is a group isomorphism. So every inner semidirect product can be seen as an outer semidirect product via the conjugation action of $H$ on $N$.

If on the other hand $N$ and $H$ are two groups and $\theta \colon H \to \operatorname{Aut}(N)$ a group homomorphism, then we can regard both $N$ and $H$ as subgroups $\widehat{N}$ and $\widehat{H}$ of the outer semidirect product $N \rtimes_\theta H$ via the inclusions
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  N &\to N \rtimes_\theta H \,, &\quad n &\mapsto (n,1) \,,
  \\
  H &\to N \rtimes_\theta H \,, &\quad h &\mapsto (1,h) \,.
\end{alignat*}
It then follows for those subgroup $\widehat{N}$ and $\widehat{H}$ that both $\widehat{N} \cdot \widehat{H} = \widehat{N} \rtimes_\theta \widehat{H}$ and $\widehat{N} \cap \widehat{H} = 1$, and that the subgroup $\widehat{N}$ is normal in $N \rtimes_\theta H$. The group $N \rtimes_\theta H$ is therefore the inner semidirect product of its subgroups $\widehat{N}$ and $\widehat{H}$, with $\widehat{N}$ normal.

PS: So given any two groups $H$ and $N$ there may exist multiple outer semidirect products $N \rtimes_\theta H$ because we can choose different group homomorphisms $\theta \colon H \to \operatorname{Aut}(N)$. But if we are given an inner semidirect product $G = N \rtimes H$ (i.e. we are given the group $G$ and its subgroups $H$ and $N$ such that $G = N \rtimes H$) then we are also implicitely given a group homomorphism $\theta \colon H \to \operatorname{Aut}(N)$ with $G \cong N \rtimes_\theta H$: The homomorphism $\theta$ is hidden in the group structure of $G$ and can be retrieved via the conjugation action of $H$ on $N$.

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer! Very helpful!

Comment: So once you choose a (non-trivial) homomorhpism φ and form the external semidirect product of the unrelated groups H and N, the resulting group G always has a subgroup isomorphic to H acting on a normal subgroup isomorphic to N **by conjugation**, the difference being that different choices of φ give potentially non-isomorphic groups, with different subgroup lattices, so inside each of those, the copies of H and N 'occupy different roles' and thus 'conjugation by H' still means something diferent?

Comment: I ask this because the fact that you can choose diffetent φ but the resulting group nevertheless always is the 'inner smidirect product' of its subgroups (H acts on N by conjugation) always confused me.

Answer (score 2):

**Definition**: A *semidirect product* of two abstract groups $H$ and $K$ is a group $G$ containing (isomorphic copies of) $H$ and $K$ as subgroups, with $H$ normal inside $G$, and such that $G$ factors uniquely as $G = HK$ (the uniqueness is equivalent to asking that $H \cap K = 1$).

**Fact**: Any semidirect product of $H$ and $K$ induces a homomorphism $K \to \operatorname{Aut}H$ by conjugation (this works since $H$ is normal).

**Theorem** (existence and uniqueness): Given abstract groups $H$, $K$ and a homomorphism $\phi:K \to \operatorname{Aut}H$, there exists a semidirect product of $H$ and $K$ ("outer semidirect product") $G = H \rtimes_\phi K$ inducing $\phi$. Moreover, any semidirect product of $H$ and $K$ inducing $\phi$ is isomorphic to $H \rtimes_\phi K$.

**Note**: Two different homomorphisms $K \to \operatorname{Aut}H$ can induce the same semidirect product. For example, let $K = \mathbb{Z}$, let $H$ be any nonabelian group, say with $h \in H \setminus Z(H)$, and consider the conjugation homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z} \to \operatorname{Aut}H$ defined by $\phi_1(h') = hh'h^{-1}$. By our choice of $h$, $\phi$ is a nontrivial homomorphism, but both $\phi$ and the trivial homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \operatorname{Aut}H$ yield the direct product $H \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks, A.P. Have a nice day.